# Devise - let admin user edit email templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise to manage authentication with Rails, and as part of that Devise sends out emails for confirmation, reset passwords *etc*. I can edit the template to make it customized for our brand.

What the client has requested now is trickier and I'd like some guidance; they want an admin user to be able to edit the email templates via the app.

The Devise mail templates are HAML views. I suppose I could simply store the template in the DB as a big string but the issues would be (a) the user understanding HAML (*ie*, I'd need to use an intermediate markup or TinyMCE) (b) how would I render from my controller? Magically it goes to the right view; I'm unclear how I can get a controller to say "render ".

Technically, that last rendering step seems like the blocker; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the views into your app, then just replace everything with `= @template.render`, or however you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create an `Email` model, with a wysiwyg editor to edit those emails, and then load and render that email's body if it exists, otherwise render the hard-coded template(as a fallback for test environments or if that specific email row gets deleted).

This way, no need to render haml anymore, and no need to train your admins in either html or haml.

Here is a gist that should cover it all: https://gist.github.com/walidvb/4f0968f6cae5743b67f7

PS: It is not necessary to have an `Email` class to achieve this, as the email's body can also be directly stored in the database by other means. However, using `ActiveRecord` gives convenient access to it. In my case, I already had an `Email` class.

PPS: As a safeguard against deleting the devise email, I've added an `indestructible` column. Also, to allow admin to switch back to default email, I've added an `active` column.